# Html helper to route back from a subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created an mvc3 application that allows my customers to have there own subdomain page with the application e.g. www.subdomain.mydomain.com

The problem I am now facing is the main menu and footer that is contained within my _Layout meaning if a user browses to the subdomain my links are been rendered as www.subdomain.mydomain.com/about - www.subdomain.mydomain.com/contactus etc etc.

I assume I need to create a helper to enable mapping the links back away from the subdomain but I dont have a clue where to start.....can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: how are you rendering the links? they should be rendered as `<a href="/about">About</a>` when you use the default helpers, and therefore should be relative to the current domain. They should not be absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a _SubdomainLayout page, and set the links on that page to the URL you want.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking of doing to. I was just wondering if there was a better approach vs. having 2 layout pages.